# Updating DataGrid ItemsSource does not update the custom header

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with a custom header. The DataGrid is bound to a `CollectionViewSource` property in the viewmodel.
The datagrid columns are created in codebehind.

When I change the collection, the datagrid is updated and shows the new data. However, the custom header does not update - it is still bound to old objects which should have gone out of scope.
In other words, the header is only bound the first time. After that, it hangs on to the old objects even though the ItemsSource changes.

How can I fix it so the header updates at the same time as the rest of the datagrid when the data changes?

```
<DataGrid
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="False" 
                    CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                    CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                    CanUserSortColumns="True"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PreformDataListViewSource.View}">
</DataGrid>

<!-- Custom header -->
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- HEADER 1: Extra header row. For some reason, it does not re-bind when there are 
changes to the data. 
The ToggleButton will keep showing the status of an old out-of-scope object. -->
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                            Grid.Row="0" >
                                    <ItemsControl 
                                        ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}">   
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btPlotHeader"
                                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedForPlotting, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                                                            Command="{Binding CommandPlotColumn}">
                                                    </ToggleButton>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <!-- HEADER 2: These 2 controls are the default header with sortable headings. -->
                                <DataGridColumnHeader 
                                    x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" 
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="3" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyVM: BindableBase
{
        private ObservableCollection<PreformDataVM> preformDataList;

        public MyVM()
        {
            this.PreformDataList = new ObservableCollection<PreformDataVM>();
            this.PreformDataListViewSource = new CollectionViewSource()
            {
                Source = this.PreformDataList,
            };
        }

         /// <summary>
        /// Gets the CollectionViewSource. The purpose of this collection is to preserve 
          sorting when the data is reloaded / refreshed.
        /// </summary>
        public CollectionViewSource PreformDataListViewSource
        {
            get; private set;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PreformDataVM> PreformDataList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.preformDataList;
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetProperty(ref this.preformDataList, value);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a workaround which is to recreate the DataGrid columns each time the data changes.

Previously, I would only create the columns at the start and when the data format changed.

Now the column headers always show the correct data.